# How to extract customers that are yet to complete their credit with outstanding amount and Date

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one for Credit and the second for those who have paid their credits

Table 1

```
credit_id   customer_id total_amount_given  disbursement_date
1                1              50000          2020-09-02
2                2              60000          2020-09-02
3                1              10000          2020-10-05
4                3              100000         2020-09-02
```

Table 2

```
payment_id  credit_id   amount  type             payment_timestamp
1          1            50000   disbursement    2020-10-01 10:01:12
2          2             1000   repayment       2020-10-01 10:05:12
3          1             10000  repayment       2020-10-01 10:31:01
4          2             100    repayment       2020-11-01 17:11:01
```

Definition of Total outstanding balance = total disbursed amount (type=’disbursement’ in table 2) - total repaid amount (type=’repayment’ in table 2)

Assuming that all credit tenure irrespective of the credit amount is for 90 days only.
I want to write a query to create a table that will give me total outstanding balance on each day from disbursement day till last repayment date of the rent for each customer – credit combination.

Required Table Structure

Required Table Structure
date|Customer_id|credit_id|total_amount_disbursed|total_outstanding_amount|latest_repayment_date

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you want to do. However, since you did not ask any questions, we cannot provide any answers! Please describe what you have tried and what you are stuck with! Provide exact error message or descriptiin of unexpected behaviour! Please provide sample data, expected result, and a reasonable attempt on your side to solve the problem you are facing!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: There is no disbursement for credit id = 2 so should this be ignored in your query result?

Comment: or put another way, you store the disbursement amount two places; which do you want to use?

Comment: I need a query to create a table that will give me total outstanding balance on each day from disbursement day till last repayment date of the rent for each customer – credit combination